# How to set the background color of Tab.Screen?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

As you can see below, I've tried many ways of setting the background color to transparent like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSASO.png) (UI required), all to no avail. The background remains grey-ish like the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQfTA.png)

```
  <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{
    tabBarShowLabel: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
    tabBarShowIcon: true,
    tabBarItemStyle: { width: iconwidth },
    tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent', paddingBottom: 10},
    tabBarContentContainerStyle: {backgroundColor : 'transparent', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'},
    tabBarPressColor: '#3C60AA',
    tabBarIndicatorStyle: {width: iconwidth , height: 5, backgroundColor: '#3C60AA', borderRadius: 20, marginStart: iconwidth *0.61},
    lazy: true,
    lazyPlaceholder: () => <POTab_lazy/>
  }}>

    <Tab.Screen name="POTab_1" component={POTab_1} options={{ tabBarAccessibilityLabel: 'Info',tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => ( <Image source={require('../../assets/icon_info.png')} style={{width: 30, height: 30 }}/>), }}/>
    <Tab.Screen name="POTab_2" component={POTab_2} options={{tabBarAccessibilityLabel: 'File',tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => ( <Image source={require('../../assets/icon_file.png')} style={{width: 30, height: 30 }}/>),}}/>
    <Tab.Screen name="POTab_3" component={POTab_3} options={{tabBarAccessibilityLabel: 'Attach',tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => ( <Image source={require('../../assets/icon_attach.png')} style={{width: 30, height: 30 }}/>),}}/>
    <Tab.Screen name="POTab_4" component={POTab_4} options={{tabBarAccessibilityLabel: 'Link',tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => ( <Image source={require('../../assets/icon_link.png')} style={{width: 30, height: 30 }}/>),}}/>
    <Tab.Screen name="POTab_5" component={POTab_5} options={{tabBarAccessibilityLabel: 'Timer',tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => ( <Image source={require('../../assets/icon_timer.png')} style={{width: 30, height: 30 }}/>),}}/>
  </Tab.Navigator>
```

);
}

POTab_1.js code looks like this

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-start', padding: 20 }}>
    
    <View style={{marginBottom: 15}}>
      <Text style={{color: 'grey', fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular', lineHeight: 20}}>Purchase Order</Text>
      <Text style={{color: 'black', fontFamily: 'Poppins-Bold'}}>450004892</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={{marginBottom: 15}}>
      <Text style={{color: 'grey', fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular', lineHeight: 20}}>Vendor id</Text>
      <Text style={{color: 'black', fontFamily: 'Poppins-Bold'}}>0003300000</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={{marginBottom: 15}}>
      <Text style={{color: 'grey', fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular, lineHeight: 20'}}>Vendor Name</Text>
      <Text style={{color: 'black', fontFamily: 'Poppins-Bold'}}>ITT Texas</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={{marginBottom: 15}}>
      <Text style={{color: 'grey', fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular, lineHeight: 20'}}>Item No</Text>
      <Text style={{color: 'black', fontFamily: 'Poppins-Bold'}}>00010</Text>
    </View>

  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

package.json

@react-navigation/material-top-tabs: "^6.2.2"

react-native-pager-view: "^5.4.25"

react-native-tab-view: "^3.1.1"

[for material top bar navigator reference, look here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/#installation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set background color for the whole tab bar, then we need to provide the **style** in `tabBarOptions` prop to the Tab.Navigator.

Consider the following code snippet.

```
<Tab.Navigator
  tabBarOptions={{
    style: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    }
  }}>
```

Updated your code to include `tabBarOptions`

```
<Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{
    tabBarShowLabel: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
    tabBarShowIcon: true,
    tabBarItemStyle: { width: iconwidth },
    tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent', paddingBottom: 10},
    tabBarContentContainerStyle: {backgroundColor : 'transparent', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'},
    tabBarPressColor: '#3C60AA',
    tabBarIndicatorStyle: {width: iconwidth , height: 5, backgroundColor: '#3C60AA', borderRadius: 20, marginStart: iconwidth *0.61},
    lazy: true,
    lazyPlaceholder: () => <POTab_lazy/>
  }}
  tabBarOptions={{
    style: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    }
  }}>

    <Tab.Screen name="POTab_1" component={POTab_1} options={{ tabBarAccessibilityLabel: 'Info',tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => ( <Image source={require('../../assets/icon_info.png')} style={{width: 30, height: 30 }}/>), }}/>
    <Tab.Screen name="POTab_2" component={POTab_2} options={{tabBarAccessibilityLabel: 'File',tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => ( <Image source={require('../../assets/icon_file.png')} style={{width: 30, height: 30 }}/>),}}/>
    <Tab.Screen name="POTab_3" component={POTab_3} options={{tabBarAccessibilityLabel: 'Attach',tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => ( <Image source={require('../../assets/icon_attach.png')} style={{width: 30, height: 30 }}/>),}}/>
    <Tab.Screen name="POTab_4" component={POTab_4} options={{tabBarAccessibilityLabel: 'Link',tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => ( <Image source={require('../../assets/icon_link.png')} style={{width: 30, height: 30 }}/>),}}/>
    <Tab.Screen name="POTab_5" component={POTab_5} options={{tabBarAccessibilityLabel: 'Timer',tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => ( <Image source={require('../../assets/icon_timer.png')} style={{width: 30, height: 30 }}/>),}}/>
  </Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're trying to change the screens, not the tab bar itself, I found setting `sceneContainerStyle` to be the way to do it:

```
<Tab.Navigator sceneContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}} >
```